# Access a variable in a method under a class in python

Tags: python, class, methods, static, global

```
class user_management(wx.Panel):
  def login(self):        
      # Login Function can be later integrated to allow users access to your program
      username = self.txt_Username.GetValue()
      self.frame.SetStatusText("Welcome "+username+" to the system!!")
      test = MyApp(0)
      test.MainLoop()
```

How can i access the variable username within another class:

```
class wizard(wx.wizard.Wizard):
    def on_finished(self, evt):
        totalscore = self.totalscore
        print "Final score: %s" % (totalscore)
        user = "c1021358"
        db_file="data/data.db"
        database_already_exists = os.path.exists(db_file)    
        con = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        cur = con.cursor()
        sql = "INSERT INTO scores (username,totalscore,topic) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')" % (user,totalscore,tag)
```

At the moment the user is static, however I want to make this user variable equal to the username taken from the text field box.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to store the value of `username` somewhere that both methods can see. The easiest way to do this, but almost certainly not the right one, is to make it a global variable. You can do that using the `global` keyword:

```
global username
username = ...
```

However, you are almost certainly more likely to want to store it as an attribute of some object. I don't know your architecture so I can't tell you where is best to put it, but something like a `User` or a `Settings` object would be good.

Comment: @Jeff
Could you elaborate more please on how to create the object. I will try with the global variable - but honestly I have tried before. Here is the code , I know its really badly coded and very messy - but try your best at reading it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Currently `username` is a local variable and can't be accessed outside of the method. You could make it a member variable by doing something like `self.username` instead. It would probably be a good idea to initialize it in an `__init__` method.

EDIT: katrielalex has the right idea. You probably want to store the username in something that is not part of your user_management panel. This could either be a global variable, or you could make a user class.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
# Create a global "current_user", with an initial username of None
current_user = User(None)
```

Then if you can access the username from the global User object:

```
def login(self):
    global current_user
    current_user.username = self.txt_Username.GetValue()
```

Please note this is all very general (for instance, this assumes you can only support one user at a time), but it should be able to get you started.